# postgresql - select all consequetive rows with event with specific value per group ordered by timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to define a query that selects all first consequetive rows with events with specific value per group ordered by timestamp. The unique identifier is defined as "rowid", the event is defined as "labels", the groups are defined by an "entryid". For all rows I have a timestamp "TimeStamp".

To be specific, as soon as a event happens (labels=1) the I would like to retrieve all repeated values of 1 for a given entryid until labels becomes another value. If the value becomes different than zero, I don't want to retrieve the rows.

The data can be defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
 rowid int8 PRIMARY KEY,
 patientid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 studyid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 entryid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 labels int8,
 "TimeStamp" TIMESTAMP
 );


INSERT INTO test_table(rowid, patientid, studyid, entryid, labels, "TimeStamp")
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-01-11 00:51:14'),
        (4, 1, 1, 1, 1, '2015-01-11 00:54:14'),
        (3, 1, 1, 1, 3, '2015-01-11 00:53:14'),
        (2, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-01-11 00:52:14'),
        (5, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-01-11 00:55:14'),
        (6, 1, 2, 2, 1, '2015-01-12 08:10:14'),
        (7, 1, 2, 2, 0, '2015-01-12 08:11:14'),
        (8, 1, 2, 2, 1, '2015-01-12 08:13:25'),
        (9, 2, 1, 3, 0, '2015-01-12 09:14:25'),
        (10, 2, 1, 3, 0, '2015-01-12 09:15:25'),
        (11, 2, 1, 3, 2, '2015-01-12 09:17:25'),
        (12, 2, 1, 3, 6, '2015-01-12 09:18:25'),
        (13, 3, 1, 4, 0, '2015-01-13 07:14:25'),
        (14, 3, 1, 4, 0, '2015-01-13 07:15:25'),
        (15, 3, 1, 4, 1, '2015-01-13 07:17:25'),
        (16, 3, 1, 4, 0, '2015-01-13 07:18:25'),
        (17, 3, 1, 4, 0, '2015-01-13 07:18:25'),
        (18, 4, 1, 5, 0, '2015-01-13 03:14:25'),
        (19, 4, 1, 5, 0, '2015-01-13 03:15:25'),
        (20, 4, 1, 5, 0, '2015-01-13 03:17:25'),
        (21, 4, 1, 5, 1, '2015-01-13 03:18:25'),
        (22, 4, 2, 6, 0, '2015-01-13 03:12:13'),
        (23, 4, 2, 6, 1, '2015-01-13 03:14:07'),
        (24, 4, 2, 6, 1, '2015-01-13 03:17:05'),
        (25, 4, 2, 6, 0, '2015-01-13 03:19:42'),
        (26, 4, 2, 6, 0, '2015-01-13 03:22:51'),
        (27, 5, 1, 7, 1, '2015-02-13 03:19:42'),
        (28, 5, 1, 7, 1, '2015-02-13 03:22:51'),
        (29, 6, 1, 8, 1, '2015-02-13 03:19:42'),
        (30, 6, 1, 8, 0, '2015-02-13 03:22:51'),
        (31, 6, 1, 8, 0, '2015-02-13 03:23:42'),
        (32, 6, 1, 8, 1, '2015-02-13 03:24:51'),
        (33, 7, 1, 9, 1, '2015-02-13 03:19:42'),
        (34, 7, 1, 9, 0, '2015-02-13 03:22:51'),
        (35, 7, 1, 9, 1, '2015-02-13 03:23:42'),
        (36, 7, 1, 9, 1, '2015-02-13 03:24:51'),
        (37, 7, 1, 9, 0, '2015-02-13 03:25:51'),
        (38, 7, 1, 10, 1, '2015-02-13 03:19:42'),
        (39, 7, 1, 10, 0, '2015-02-13 03:22:51'),
        (40, 7, 1, 10, 0, '2015-02-13 03:23:42'),
        (41, 7, 1, 10, 0, '2015-02-13 03:24:51'),
        (42, 7, 1, 10, 1, '2015-02-13 03:25:51'),
        (43, 7, 1, 11, 1, '2015-02-13 03:19:42'),
        (44, 7, 1, 11, 1, '2015-02-13 03:22:51'),
        (45, 7, 1, 11, 0, '2015-02-13 03:23:42'),
        (46, 7, 1, 11, 0, '2015-02-13 03:24:51'),
        (47, 7, 1, 11, 1, '2015-02-13 03:25:51'),
        (48, 7, 1, 11, 1, '2015-02-13 03:27:51'),
        (49, 7, 1, 12, 1, '2015-02-13 03:19:42'),
        (50, 7, 1, 12, 0, '2015-02-13 03:22:51'),
        (51, 7, 1, 12, 1, '2015-02-13 03:23:42'),
        (52, 7, 1, 12, 0, '2015-02-13 03:24:51'),
        (53, 7, 1, 12, 1, '2015-02-13 03:25:51'),
        (54, 7, 1, 12, 0, '2015-02-13 03:27:51'),
        (55, 7, 1, 13, 0, '2015-02-13 03:24:51'),
        (56, 7, 1, 13, 1, '2015-02-13 03:25:51'),
        (57, 7, 1, 13, 1, '2015-02-13 03:27:51')
;
```

I both need the consequetive (first repeating) values pr group ordered by timestamp for zeros and ones.

For the zeros, the expected output contains the following 21 rowids:
(1, 2, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 22, 30, 31, 34, 39, 40 ,41, 45, 46, 50, 55)

For the ones, the expected output contains the following 16 rowids:
(4, 6, 15, 21, 23, 24, 27, 28, 29, 33, 38, 43, 44, 49, 56, 57)

I hope someone can help me defined a correct and query for this problem.

best regards.

Comment: What do you mean by consequetive? what is repeating here?

Comment: I mean as soon the value becomes 1, I would like to retrieve all rows with value 1 for the given entryid. But if the value changes to be different from 1 and becomes 1 again I need a query that does NOT return the ones.